# How to replace values in dataframe between value x and y

Tags: r, replace

Suppose dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(x = rpois(10,2), y = rpois(10,2), z = rpois(10,2), q = rpois(10,2), t = rpois(10,2))
```

I want to turn all cells between 2 and 6 into 1s and all cells below 2 or higher than 6 into 0s.

The following doesn't work:

```
df[df < 2] <- "0"
df[df > 6] <- "0"
df[df > 2] <- "1"
df[df < 6] <- "1"
```

Because the last step turns all the values beneath 6 into 1s (doesn't stop at 2).

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to a logical matrix and then coerce to binary with `+` and assign it back to te dataset

```
df[] <- +(df > 2 & df < 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ifelse()`, i.e. `df <- as.data.frame(ifelse(df >= 2 & df <= 6,1, 0))`. Can use nested `ifelse` too if you had additional checks. Otherwise can define a function and `sapply()` over the columns, or `mapply` over the data.frame (will probably have to similarly change from matrix).

Answer (score 1):

If all data are of the same class (i.e., integers) consider using a matrix instead of a data frame.

```
m <- as.matrix(df)
i <- m %in% 3:5
m[i] <- 1
m[!i] <- 0
```